# How do you manage 3rd person git repositories in your project? (ex. Twig/Assetic/..)

Tags: git, data-structures, project-management, directory, project

I've made a personal light framework in PHP which matches my needs for a framework.
I'm using different 3rd party libraries, like SwiftMailer, Twig, Assetic, Facebook PHP api, ...

How do you manage these sources codes from 3rd party libraries?
Do you add it as a submodule into your project, and just do a pull to get the latest version?
Or do you just copy the code into your project dir and do the updates yourself?

Most code repositories are structured like this:

- docs
- src
- tests

So in my framework dir it looks like this, and us the vendor dirs as submodule from a remote project:

- docs
- src

  - vendor

    - Assetic (clone of remote repo)
    - src
    - ...
- tests

Is this the way to go? Or how do you suggest doing this?
During a capistrano deploy, all the submodule repositories will be pulled from the remote servers.

Edit: I must say that I use the framework as submodule in other projects. So the framework is a submodule in a project, and the framework itself also has submodules in it..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I generally use a `vendor` folder, either top-level or under `src` or `lib` that holds the submodules, and use the the `--recurse-submodules` option when pulling, and `--recursive` with `git submodule update` and `git submodule status`. I *think* capistrano can handle this use case decently, but I'm not familiar enough with it to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I manage every project separetaly.
Every project folder could contain all files for correct build - so all referenced files is included in "refs" directory. In this case is build easy: get latest version of "src, refs & build" directory, run the build script. The output is in "bin" directory.

The "refs" folder is consuming the disk size, but it's much simpliest than managing cross-project references with correction versions (and branches).

- 3rdParty-Project-A
- 3rdParty-Project-B

  - src  // source code & resources
  - refs // referenced binaries in correct version
  - build // build script
  - bin // builded binaries & related files
  - deploy // files used for deploy (setup.exe, setup.msi, etc...)
  - ... other folders ...
- MyProject-A
- MyProject-B

  - src
  - refs

    - 3rdParty-Project-B // there are referenced files from 3rdParty-Project-B
    - MyProject-A // there are referenced files from MyProject-A
  - build
  - bin
  - deploy